# Quiero obtener el valor de una variable dentro de una funcion para llamarla en otra funcion y utilizar ese valor. ¿Como Hago?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables-globales

Estoy empezando a usar Javascript con jquery y necesito el valor que obtuve de un .parentElement en este caso es el id de un elemento, pero requiero de ese valor para usarlo en otra función y realizar mi siguiente proceso.

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
function capt(){
     $(document).on('click', '.procesar_hab_now', function(){
          let captdata = $(this)[0].parentElement;
          let id = $(captdata).attr('getNumHAB');    //<--id que necesito
     });
}


function proceso(){
     var id_result = (/*la variable o valor de la anterior function*/);  
     ...
}
```

Que solución me dan a este problema. Por favor ayúdenme ¡Gracias!.

Comment: Puedes pasarla como argumento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes una funcion que realiza algún proceso para obtener un valor ( en tu caso obtienes el valor del id que necesitas ), en vez que tu función simplemente asigne el valor a una variable, puedes hacer que devuelva el valor.

```
function capt(){
     //... tu codigo
     return $(captdata).attr('getNumHAB');
}
```

Y luego en tu segunda función, a la hora de querer asignar a alguna variable de dentro de la función el valor que obtienes en la otra funcion, solamente tienes que igualar la variable a la función

```
function proceso(){
     var id_result = capt();  
     ...
}
```

De esta manera se llamará al a función capt() la que devolvera el valor que quieres a la variable id_result.